# Why does Photoshop CS6 open new documents in grayscale mode?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color-spaces, grayscale

When I open a new document in Photoshop CS6, it opens in grayscale mode. How can I change this?

Answer (score 2):

In the 'New document' window you can change the 'Color Mode' to RGB/CMYK and then this is saved as a default, so every other new document will be set to RGB/CMYK.

[image]